# Can a repulsion motor be connected like a series or shunt DC motor?

Tags: induction-motor, brushed-dc-motor, universal-motor

Recently I bought an old repulsion-start induction-run motor made by Asincron in Argentina, exactly identical to the one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QyWPDfUVFY).
I can't find much documentation and information about how exactly their rotor (repulsion motors in general) is wound.

Is the winding the same as in DC brushed motors?

If it is, would it be possible to connect and use it as a series or shunt motor in DC?

I'm aware it has not been designed for that and will probably work poorly, I'm just curious.

I'm also aware that if it does work as an universal motor then it risks disintegrating the rotor at high speeds it could develop, I won't let that happen.

Answer (score 0):

in a repulsion motor the rotor has switched electric circuits, but only gets current by induction from the field winding.

it's not going to work as a DC motor as all the armature current comes by induction.

it may be possible to re-wire the motor as a series or shunt DC motor, you would need to isolate the brushes, as in the original the brushes are all grounded.

The motor in the video has a centrifugal switch bank that shorts out the rotor. that would need to be removed for DC operation.

Comment: Yes, yes, I was pretending to mean rewiring when I said "connecting" in my post. I know I can rewire the brushes to feed the armature just like in a DC motor, and that I can also adjust the angle of the brushes for correct operation. My doubt was if the winding of the armature in a repulsion motor has the same pattern of the winding in the armature of a DC motor, of if it's so different it won't work at all even if I reconnect it.

Comment: it will probably work, but I can't say how well it will work.